# Determining NuGet packages to include to resolve Usings

Tags: nuget

Using Sitecore 8.2, Im spending a fair bit of time trying to figure out which packages to include and there doesn't seem to be helpful documentation for this.

For example, I have some code which uses [AuthorizedReportingUserFilter] and I believe that's contained in the name space Sitecore.Cintel.Endpoint.Plumbing, but there isn't a package with Cintel in the name.

This is just one example and may be simple to find the package, but Im interested to hear if there's a way to determine the package quickly that can be used for all namespaces.

Comment: There is a package called [Sitecore.Cintel.NoReferences](https://sitecore.myget.org/feed/sc-packages/package/nuget/Sitecore.Cintel.NoReferences) , what else you could not find?

Comment: Also, have you checked this page? [Sitecore Packages](https://sitecore.myget.org/gallery/sc-packages)

Answer (score 2):

### Finding Matching DLLs

There is no documentation, and unfortunately it's sometimes an educated guess which DLL contains the code you need to reference.

Since you know the Class/Namespace you are looking for, you can use a search tool to search through all the DLLs on the filesystem to find a match. I have found this to be the quickest way to narrow down to at least a set of matching DLLs. My personal preference is [GrepWin from Stefan Tools](http://tools.stefankueng.com/grepWin.html), use whatever similar tools you prefer:

[image: grepWin]

Note that this is a grep tool and you can use regular expressions if you need to find matches using some extra logic.

### Verifying using a Decompiler

You can use a decompiler to confirm the match is correct, or if you find multiple matches load them all to find the correct DLL. My personal preference is [JetBrains dotPeek Decompiler](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) but use which ever similar tool you prefer. You can use the `Go to Everything / Type` (Ctrl + T) or `Go to String` (Ctrl + Alt + T) from the navigate menu to help find the type.

[image: dotPeek]

If you are already inspecting code in a decompiler then it's possible to sometimes figure out the DLL name from the `using` statements that are referenced in the code. It may also be possible to inspect the references:

[image: dotPeek references]

Otherwise over time with experience, you learn which DLLs (most likely) contain the code you need. I've found the above techniques to serve me well though.

Comment: Worth noting that Resharper does a pretty good job of figuring this out as well. Both via references but even NuGets.

Comment: @MarkCassidy I agree, but unless one of the projects has a reference to "Sitecore.Cintel" (in this case) it generally did not work for me. Not sure if it caches references or how it resolves NuGet without a reference elsewhere in the solution... But a very good point.

Answer (score 1):

### Downloading the Sitecore Zip Files for DLL's

I have found a lot of success taking the WebRoot Zip file for various Sitecore versions that I am wanting to target, and unzipping the bin directory to a location.

### Using dotPeek to decompile and search

From there, using [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), which is a free utility, and open various bin directories in it.  I keep every version of Sitecore in the list.

From there, you can search for a class, type, or even a string (anything really), and the search results will direct you to exactly which DLL is it located in.

### Finding the NuGet Package

Once you know what DLL you're looking for, then it's a matter of finding it on the Sitecore NuGet repository. There are two versions of almost every DLL available:

1. Library with Dependencies

   1. This will show up like ***Sitecore.Kernel.DLL***
   2. Installing this DLL will also install ALL dependent NuGet packages
   3. This generally installs more references than one would like, so the alternative is to install the *NoReferences* DLL.
2. Library with No References

   1. This will show up like ***Sitecore.Kernel.DLL.NoReferences***
   2. This will ONLY install the single library reference into the solution.

Hope this helps!